# what is wrong with this python code implementation

Tags: python, server

Below is the code for establishing multiple TCP sockets in python. But it does not work. What could be wrong?

```py
    Exception in thread Thread-1 (clientthread): Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\kishore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner self.run() line 975, in run , self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs) line 10, in clientthread data = conn.recv(8192) ^^^^^^^^^ AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'recv'
```

Code:

```
#!usr/bin/python

import threading
from threading import *
import socket
import sys

def clientthread(conn):
    buffer=""
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(8192)        
        buffer+=data
        print (buffer)
        print("data recieved")
    #conn.sendall(reply)
    conn.close()

def main():
    try:
        host = '10.102.3.16'
        port = 1000
        tot_socket = 6
        list_sock = []
        for i in range(tot_socket):
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
            s.bind((host, (port*(i+1))))
            s.listen(10)
            list_sock.append(s)
            print ("[*] Server listening on %s %d" %(host, (port*(i+1))))

        while 1:
            for j in range(len(list_sock)):
                conn, addr = list_sock[j].accept()
                print ('[*] Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
                threading.Thread(target=clientthread,args=(1,)).start()
                print(threading.active_count())
        s.close()

    except KeyboardInterrupt as msg:
        sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What went wrong?

Comment: each `conn, addr = list_sock[j].accept()` will wait for that one socket to get a connection request, regardless of what is happening with the other sockets. If you want a bunch of listeners, you should create a thread that does the accept for each of them. That thread would create threads for receivers. That's the blocking thread pattern for sockets. Other options are using poll or select or asyncio to handle a bunch of sockets on one thread.

Comment: I am using Hercules TCP client to send and recieve data from server. I get the following error: 3Exception in thread 
Thread-1 (clientthread):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gary\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  line 975, in run ,   self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  line 10, in clientthread
    data = conn.recv(8192)        
           ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'recv'

Comment: But `args=(1,)` - That means you are supplying the value `1` to `clientthread()`. Did you mean: `args=(conn,)`?

Comment: oops. That was silly. But still I did not get data recieved print message for the data sent from client

Comment: Which port are using using with the tcp client? This code will first listen on `10.102.3.16:1000`.

Comment: I wish to talk to 6 clients starting from 1000 to 6000 respectively connected to server socket

Comment: But that has fixed the error you reported. That closes this question.

Comment: But I am unable to talk to more than one client. Default is 1000. Server does not respond to clients other than port 1000

Comment: Now that this error has been fixed that allows you to see the next problem. That sounds like a brand new question for you to write.

Comment: I am hoping to close this issue in this thread

Comment: Unfortunately stackoverflow doesn't work like that. This question is like many where the OP has used the wrong (or none) arguments for their thread. If you want to solve a different problem you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You just passed the wrong argument to the thread to give to the function.

You passed `args=(1,)` instead of `args=(conn,)`:

```
threading.Thread(target=clientthread,args=(conn,)).start()
```